# SQL Server dateformat query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realise that you can use `SET DATEFORMAT` to alter the way that a string is parsed but is the following unambiguous:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '02Oct15')
```

Is there any circumstances that this would be interpreted as 15th October 2002?

Comment: Is that date 2015-10-02, or 1915-10-02?

Comment: Just use YYYYMMDD, it works, with all settings

Comment: @jarlh 2002-10-15. See the last sentence

Comment: @MegaTron, just too confusing... I say the same as JamesZ, use YYYYMMDD format always!

Comment: is that the format of your input?  how it's interpreted may depend on settings, you'll need to test in your environment.

Comment: @JamesZ that is the format that has been provided - I can't change that

Comment: @Beth my question is does it really depend on your setting? I can only get it to parse as 2nd October 2015.

Comment: if you're confident all the clients have the same settings as yours and you've tested all the dates that may have a conflict, you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The century conversion will be an issue in 35 years (the y2k50, there is an amusing thought), but until then it's unambiguous. Any attempt to pass an invalid date in the first section results in a conversion error rather than it treating the third section as a date instead of a year.

Finally changing the default language (which changes the default date format) uses the same conversion (British), or causes it error out (Italian). Still as others have mentioned, storing dates in this format is a bad idea, however unless I miss my guess this seems like your importing data from a report, so you probably don't have much control over it. Anyway hope that helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make `02Oct15` to become `October 15, 2002`. However, if all three date components are numbers, it's easy to make that cast:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '02Oct15'), -- October 2, 2015
       CONVERT(DATE, '021015')   -- October 15, 2002
```

I suspect that once you introduce natural language to the string, SQL Server use culture-specific rules to convert the date components. But in the end, only Microsoft knows what SQL Server's string-to-date algorithm is.